# What's the equivalent of set_value in pandas for inserting string into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying:

```
df = df.add(i, 'div', True)
```

But it inserts `1` instead of `True`

EDIT:

i is the i in a range(len(df)) forloop

I'm trying to set an element in the dataframe to a string

Comment: Are you trying to append to a DataFrame or change a value in the current DataFrame. Is `i` the index value?

Comment: df.set_value(index=1, col=1, value='fun')

Comment: I get the error 'ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'hidden' when the value is a string

Comment: Would you show the part of your df. and tell us your specific purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want just

> "trying to set an element in the dataframe to a string"

this could be realised with:

```
for i in range(len(df["div"])):
    df.loc[i,"div"]= "True"

print(df)

>>>    div
0  True
1  True
2  True
3  True
4  True
5  True
```